# What is the name of this plant I found in a park?

Tags: botany, species-identification

I found this on Garret Mountain in Paterson, New Jersey, USA. Does anybody know the name of this plant?

[image]

Comment: @Always_Confused For a good botanist, most species can be identified even without flowers. If this would have been a North-European species, I'd probably be able to tell you what it was.

Comment: Today i saw them also in dover, nj usa. The enviroment is swamp area. Same in paterson park. Their sizes are around 30 cm, 40cm. Actually i see them all over the new jersey. I did not realize any flower.

Comment: related: [this answer](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/222/do-plants-produce-any-heat/273#273) containing the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6WL8Z.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is <strike>**Lysichiton americanus**</strike>,  skunk cabbage. It has these large, rolled-up leaves and grows in wet habitats as you describe. In Europe, it is an invasive species, but in America it is native. I am not 100% sure, because I don't know if there are any similar species in the US.

**EDIT**
As Anongoodnurse pointed out, I was right to be unsure. This is [Eastern skunk cabbage, Symplocarpus foetides](http://urbanecologycenter.org/blog/native-plant-eastern-skunk-cabbage.html). This species occurs in the Eastern parts of the USA.

[image]

Comment: I found that also they call skunk cabbage.

Comment: @RHA wow a command for strikeout.